# To disengage mouseover event after executing it once

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mouseover, addeventlistener

I am trying to display an error using mouseover event but after displaying the error, I want other functionalities to resume but the mouseover event keep interfering.

The other click event works perfectly but the mouseover event shows up before I click.

I have used document.location.reload() and that annuls it.

But I want something without reloading the page.

```
let checkbtn = document.getElementById('checkbtn');
let cancelbtn = document.getElementById('cancelbtn');

const cubeIt=(num)=> num**3;
const numIt = (str)=> parseInt(str);
const addIt =(total, curr)=> total + curr;

const errorHandler=()=>{
    display.innerHTML = `<div class="result"><h2> Invalid input</h2> <h2>length</h2></div>`
}

const isArmstrong=(e)=>{

    let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    let display = document.getElementById('display');
    let inputSplit = input.split("")
    let theMath = inputSplit.map(numIt).map(cubeIt).reduce(addIt);


    if(input.length == 3 && theMath == input){ 
        display.innerHTML = `<div class="result"><h2>TRUE</h2><h2> ${input} is Armstrong</h2></div>`
    }
    else if(input.length >= 4){
        document.getElementById('checkbtn').disabled = true

        checkbtn.addEventListener('mouseover', errorHandler, false)
        document.getElementById('checkbtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    else{
        display.innerHTML = `<div class="result"><h2>False</h2></div>`

    }
    e.preventDefault();
}

const toClear=()=>{
    let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    let display = document.getElementById('display');
    let form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.reset();
    display.innerHTML =``;
}


checkbtn.addEventListener('click', isArmstrong);
cancelbtn.addEventListener('click', toClear);
```

Comment: why not show the error after the click is done?, why is the reason behind using mouseover?

Comment: you can also debounce or throttle the function in the case you need to use mouseover, that event runs a lot of times if you are moving the mouse over the object, more explanation here: https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Jquery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function? It will call the event function only once then remove the listener.

If you really are set on using pure js, then you could just add this to your event callback function,

```
checkbtn.removeEventListener('mouseover', errorHandler, false);
```